# Logic in looping through template variables

Tags: php, templates

I'm trying to start using templates in my scripts, however I have problems looping through the variables in my template. 
I've created a simple template script and my problem is that it only replaces 1  of my variables instead of all of them. If I use `.=` the problem persist ( I only replace 1 variable at the time).  Could anyone help me with the logic of my script?

My PHP

```
<?php
$data= array('uno'=>'1','dos'=>'2','tres'=>'3','cuatro'=>'4','cinco'=>'5');

function tpl ($data,$tpl = null) {

    foreach ( $data as $find => $replace ) {
            $return = str_replace('{'.$find.'}',$replace,$tpl);
    }

    return $return;
}

echo tpl($data, file_get_contents('tpl.tpl'));
?>
```

My HTML template

```
<html>
<h1>{uno}</h1>
<h2>{dos}</h2>
<h3>{tres}</h3>
<h4>{cuatro}</h4>
<h5>{cinco}</h5>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are going to build something big try using ready template engines as Smarty .. http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple problem, you always start over the replace within `$tpl` data. Always rewrite the variable content:

```
function tpl ($data,$tpl = null) {

    $return  = $tpl; // this will be in foreach and will get rewritten.
    foreach ( $data as $find => $replace ) {
            $return = str_replace('{'.$find.'}', $replace, $return); // note $return from here
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your code is, you are always replacing data in fresh copy of $tpl variable, so that is why you see only one variable is replaced. You have to update your $tpl variable after every replace so that all variables get replaced.

make following changes to fix this issue

```
foreach ( $data as $find => $replace ) {
        $tpl = str_replace('{'.$find.'}',$replace,$tpl);
}

return $tpl;
```

This will fix your issue.